# Isn't modopt keyword included in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net

Which version of .NET framework contains the keyword **modopt**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modopt is only used in IL.  It is the job of a .NET language compiler to interpret and generate it.  Ecma-335, Partition II, chapter 7.1.1 mentions it:

> Custom modifiers, defined using modreq
>   (“required modifier”) and modopt
>   (“optional modifier”), are similar to
>   custom attributes (§21) except that
>   modifiers are part of a signature
>   rather than being attached to a
>   declaration.
>
> [Rationale: The distinction between
>   required and optional modifiers is
>   important to tools other than the CLI
>   that deal with the metadata, typically
>   compilers and program analysers. A
>   required modifier indicates that there
>   is a special semantics to the modified
>   item that should not be ignored, while
>   an optional modifier can simply be
>   ignored.
>
> For example, the const qualifier in
>   the C programming language can be
>   modelled with an optional modifier
>   since the caller of a method that has
>   a const-qualified parameter need not
>   treat it in any special way. On the
>   other hand, a parameter that shall be
>   copy-constructed in C++ shall be
>   marked with a required custom
>   attribute since it is the caller who
>   makes the copy. end rationale]

In other words, it allows adding metadata to declarations that do not matter to the CLR but do matter to the language.  The C++/CLI compiler in particular uses it.  Necessarily so, .NET has no equivalent for the *const* keyword for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `modopt` isn't an actual keyword in any .NET language (i.e. you cannot write `modopt` in C#). It is a custom modifier generated by the C++/CLI compiler, which first appeared with .NET 2.0, so I suppose that `modopt` has been added to .NET runtime at the same time.